# How to connect postgres database to an html webpage using node js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql

I have a postgres database and I'm trying to connect it to an html file so that we can print the information on our database onto our webpage. I'm currently using node js to try and connect our database to the html file we have.
I used this website https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser/ as a guide. The website is for mssql so I tried to adjust it for postgres but had no luck getting it to work. I started off by simply trying to print one of the tables onto a browser but would eventually want to know how to format it onto the html file so it outputs where I want it to.

So far I get a "pg is not defined" error on the browser page and haven't been able to figure out how to fix it. Below is the server.js file I'm using. As well as the home.html I want to connect it to.

(I have already installed express and pg so I know that's not the issue)

```js
// Requiring modules
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const {Pool} = require('pg');
  
// Get request
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  
    // Config your database credential
    const pool = new pg.Pool({
        user: 'postgres',
        password: '<password>',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 5432,
        database: 'online_store'
    })
  
    // Connect to your database
    pool.connect(config, function (err) {
  
        // Create Request object to preform
        // query operation
        var request = new pool.Request();
  
        // Query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from products',
            function (err, records) {
  
                if (err) console.log(err)
  
                // Send records as a response
                // to browser
                res.send(records);
  
            });
    });
});
  
var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is listening at port 5000...');
});

// http://localhost:5000/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
const {Client} = require('pg')
const client = new Client({
  user: "postgres", 
  password: "<password>",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  database: "online_store"
})

client.connect()
.then(() => console.log("Connected succesfully"))
.catch(e => console.log(e))
//.finally(() => client.end()) 
></script>

<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>St. Wear - Store</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url( https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1591/4511/products/main1_wide.jpg?v=1570574222);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
       background-attachment: fixed;
       overflow:scroll;
      }
      .page-header {
      padding-top:20px;
    }
      p {
        font-size:18px;
      }
      h1{
        color:black;
      }
      h2{
        color:red;
        background-color:yellow;
      }
      .row > div{
        background-size:cover;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-color:;
        
      }
      .row > div:nth-of-type(1){
        background-color:
      }
      h3 {
        color:blue;
      }
      .thumbnail > img {
        padding-left:auto;
        padding-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        width:280px;
        height:280px;
      }
      .caption > p {
        padding-left:auto;
        padding-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        color:green;
      }
      .caption > h3 {
        padding-left:auto;
        padding-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
      }
      #carousel-example-generic img{
        width:100%;
    }
      .carousel-inner{
        width:100%;
        max-height: 500px !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

      <header class="container">
   <div class="nav navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="http://jsbin.com/vumidan/">Home</a></li>
         <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="http://jsbin.com/dicawa/">Sneakers</a></li>
         <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="http://jsbin.com/vofasak">Streatwear</a></li>
         <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="http://jsbin.com/joqurew/" target="_blank">Skatebaords</a></li>
         <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="http://jsbin.com/yohikog/" target="_blank">Info</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <header>
    
  <div class="page-header"><h1>Welcome to St. Wear</h1><small>Made by Group idk</small></div>
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a8/07/21/a8072176f040ce84f7efa62da2b89df0.jpg" alt="Swinging">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Best seller 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a8/07/21/a8072176f040ce84f7efa62da2b89df0.jpg" alt="Trial">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Best seller 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a8/07/21/a8072176f040ce84f7efa62da2b89df0.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Best seller 3
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
    <!--  clothe pods  -->
    
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-b8nauo3un5/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/8554/34957/973mpr%20-%20oxford__08932.1617639537.png?c=2?imbypass=on" alt="name_images"> <!-- fix names -->
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Grey Pants</h3>
        <p>
            
            src= 'index.js' 
        </p>
         <a href="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bwear.com%2Fplain-sweatpants-oxford%2F&psig=AOvVaw2lrfLwAMYhry5zMOkUMnRO&ust=1618466857534000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMipy4SJ_e8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Buy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-b8nauo3un5/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/8554/34957/973mpr%20-%20oxford__08932.1617639537.png?c=2?imbypass=on" alt="name_images"> <!-- fix names -->
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Grey Pants</h3>
        <p>$29.99</p>
         <a href="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bwear.com%2Fplain-sweatpants-oxford%2F&psig=AOvVaw2lrfLwAMYhry5zMOkUMnRO&ust=1618466857534000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMipy4SJ_e8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Buy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-b8nauo3un5/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/8554/34957/973mpr%20-%20oxford__08932.1617639537.png?c=2?imbypass=on" alt="name_images"> <!-- fix names -->
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Grey Pants</h3>
        <p>$29.99</p>
         <a href="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bwear.com%2Fplain-sweatpants-oxford%2F&psig=AOvVaw2lrfLwAMYhry5zMOkUMnRO&ust=1618466857534000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMipy4SJ_e8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Buy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-b8nauo3un5/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/8554/34957/973mpr%20-%20oxford__08932.1617639537.png?c=2?imbypass=on" alt="name_images"> <!-- fix names -->
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Grey Pants</h3>
        <p>$29.99</p>
         <a href="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bwear.com%2Fplain-sweatpants-oxford%2F&psig=AOvVaw2lrfLwAMYhry5zMOkUMnRO&ust=1618466857534000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMipy4SJ_e8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Buy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-b8nauo3un5/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/8554/34957/973mpr%20-%20oxford__08932.1617639537.png?c=2?imbypass=on" alt="name_images"> <!-- fix names -->
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Grey Pants</h3>
        <p>$29.99</p>
         <a href="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bwear.com%2Fplain-sweatpants-oxford%2F&psig=AOvVaw2lrfLwAMYhry5zMOkUMnRO&ust=1618466857534000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMipy4SJ_e8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Buy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-b8nauo3un5/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/8554/34957/973mpr%20-%20oxford__08932.1617639537.png?c=2?imbypass=on" alt="name_images"> <!-- fix names -->
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Grey Pants</h3>
        <p>$29.99</p>
         <a href="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bwear.com%2Fplain-sweatpants-oxford%2F&psig=AOvVaw2lrfLwAMYhry5zMOkUMnRO&ust=1618466857534000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMipy4SJ_e8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Buy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
.finally(() => client.end()) 
></script>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: const {Pool} = require('pg'); <- this means you have a variable Pool which is the value of pg.Pool - via 'object destructuring'.  const pool = new pg.Pool({ <- this should just be Pool, as pg doesn't exist.